# How to run linux command without extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, installation

I'm in the process of installing a data management software, and as part of this I had to extract .tar.gz files etc, which wasn't a problem. After the first extraction, there was now two more .tar.gz files in the directory, together with what I think is a bash command file or something of the sort. It is called "xyinstal". This install has no file extension when using ls -ltr, and I have no idea how to use this instal function to install the last two .tar.gz files. When I VI this file, it is clear that it is a procedural file in order to automatically untar the files passed to it, and to install as well. I just have no idea how to call this. The help manual says that the two tar files must not be manually extracted, but that the install function must be "run". Nothing I do seems to work.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you tried running xyinstall?
>.xyinstall

Comment: yes. It says Command not found.

Comment: I meant ./xyinstall sorry.

Comment: Read the comments below.

Comment: what interpreter is set on top of the file's content? There should be something like #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/ksh...

Comment: give maybe a `ls -lisa .xinsta*` result and a `head -5` of your file in your post

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not have executable permission to the script.

You can do the below to give executable permission and then run it:

```
chmod +x ./xyinstal
./xyinstal
```

or use korn shell to run the script like below:

```
ksh ./xyinstal
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to invoke

```
./xyinstal
```

from the command line. Note that I've assumed it's really `xyinstal` with a single `l` at the end.

You won't be able to do this unless it's executable, but try this first.

Also, run

```
file xyinstal
```

to determine what sort of file it is before you run it.

Comment: This doesn't work. It says "No such file or directory"

Comment: Then either you're in the wrong directory, or it's not an executable. You might need `chmod a+x xyinstal` before you run it.

Comment: I ran file xyinstal and it says its a "korn shell script text executable".

Comment: You can try >bash xyinstall or even run it from the korn shell:
>ksh xyinstall
Depends on your OS and configurations

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. Perhaps it would have been clearer if I had specified that I was doing all of this on a brand new VM. The issue was that this is a Korn Shell Script, and I didn't have the Korn Shell installed on this version of linux. A simple `yum install ksh` allowed me to install the Korn Shell, and then ./xyinstal worked. Thanks for the answers and help guys.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `chmod +x xyinstal` to make the file executable and then `./xyinstal`

Answer (score 0):

When you're facing this sort of unknown file, I suggest you begin with the `file` command, which will guess the type of the file (without relying on the extension):

```
$ file xyinstal
xyinstal: ASCII text
```

If this is a text file (and the `file` command doesn't give you more information), there is a chance you find the name of the program it has to be called with in the first line:

```
$ head -n1 xyinstal
#!/usr/bin/ksh
```

This line (a shebang) tells your shell what program it should use to execute the file when you do `./xyinstal` (granted you have execution permission). Looking at it you can see if it's a shell script, python or something else.